# zsh preexec command modification

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

Is there a way to modify the command that is about to execute?
I would like to redirect the output to a file, as well as print it on the terminal.
 I found that `ls > file.txt | cat` does the job, so I would like to add that `> file.txt | cat` to any command that is about to execute.
Is there a better way to redirect to file and print to terminal? I am trying to make a logger.

Comment: tee is the command to use here, > file | cat is quite confusing

Answer (score 10):

You can change the action that is performed when you execute a line to alter the command that will be executed. This can be done by defining a function which you then bind to the enter key.

Lets first define a function that can add the '> file.txt | cat' ending to any command:

```
function log_and_accept {
    BUFFER="$BUFFER > file.txt | cat"
    zle accept-line
}
```

The next part is to actually replace the default enter key behaviour with your new function. The default behaviour we are replacing is the accept-line function, and if we look at the [zle documentation](http://www.cs.elte.hu/zsh-manual/zsh_14.html), you will see that accept-line is bound to ^J and ^M.

To bind this function to those letters you first need to turn it into a widget:

```
zle -N log_and_accept_widget log_and_accept
```

Then you can bind it, replacing the old behaviour:

```
bindkey '^J' log_and_accept_widget
bindkey '^M' log_and_accept_widget
```

Now you will be expanding that command for every single command you do. Every cd, ls, vim etc etc. As such I recommend that you define a couple more functions that actually turn this on and off:

```
function turn_on_logging {
    bindkey '^J' log_and_accept_widget
    bindkey '^M' log_and_accept_widget
}
function turn_off_logging {
    bindkey '^J' accept-line
    bindkey '^M' accept-line
}

zle -N turn_on_logging_widget turn_on_logging
zle -N turn_off_logging_widget turn_off_logging

bindkey '^P' turn_on_logging_widget
bindkey '^O' turn_off_logging_widget
```

I think you should be careful with this. After testing it a little, I quickly grew to dislike it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that, the 1 I like the most is this block I found here http://git.grml.org/?p=grml-etc-core.git;a=blob_plain;f=etc/zsh/zshrc;hb=HEAD

```
abk=(
  '...'  '../..'
  '....' '../../..'
  'BG'   '& exit'
  'C'    '| wc -l'
  'G'    '|& grep '${grep_options:+"${grep_options[*]}"}
  'H'    '| head'
  'Hl'   ' --help |& less -r'    #d (Display help in pager)
  'L'    '| less'
  'LL'   '|& less -r'
  'M'    '| most'
  'N'    '&>/dev/null'           #d (No Output)
  'R'    '| tr A-z N-za-m'       #d (ROT13)
  'SL'   '| sort | less'
  'S'    '| sort -u'
  'T'    '| tail'
  'V'    '|& vim -'
  'co'   './configure && make && sudo make install'
  'fc'   '> file.txt | cat'
)

zleiab() {
  emulate -L zsh
  setopt extendedglob
  local MATCH

  if (( NOABBREVIATION > 0 )) ; then
      LBUFFER="${LBUFFER},."
      return 0
  fi

  matched_chars='[.-|_a-zA-Z0-9]#'
  LBUFFER=${LBUFFER%%(#m)[.-|_a-zA-Z0-9]#}
  LBUFFER+=${abk[$MATCH]:-$MATCH}
}

zle -N zleiab && bindkey ",." zleiab
```

Also notice that I added `'fc'   '> file.txt | cat'` to the list `abk`

What this does in that that you type `fc` after the command and then you hit <kbd>,.</kbd> (comma and period) in rapid succession and zsh will replace `fc` for `> file.txt | cat`